# Disable ios11 HTML5 video tag goes fullscreen on pinch

Tags: safari, html5-video, fullscreen, ios11, pinchzoom

Making pinch gesture on any `<video playsinline="true"/>` that plays, makes it go fullscreen. Can't find any docs on that topic.

Comment: Hi Nikita :)
Tried `pointer-events: none;`, tried killing different parent node's events (looks like Safari does not respect any event cancelling on video) - none works.
My best current solution is to cover video element with absolute 100% same size div element with `pointer-events: all;`